# Mongo-Express not showing the Mongodb servers

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, minikube, mongo-express

I have a MongoDB replica set configured in a minikube environment and I have successfully connected the mongo-express to the replica set through the `"ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL"`. Even though they are connected I'm unable to view the status of the servers. Mind you I have set `"ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN"` to true in env of my definition file.

[this reference](https://medium.com/swlh/mongodb-replica-set-on-kubernetes-mongo-express-ui-3ee96804252#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijc0MjE3YjhkYWRiYjM2NTc4MzU4MGY5ZTkyNDg3ZDcwMWNkMzhmZTYiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.C4GKZuIPV4nK1Tt1mm36DfWlLq1nFdOzqbcO00112ggaRZc5MZh6QnGSFSTeAZZ6co4Is3C0JL0a4K5tQ9axz_-IRWHStgK_rRkJtySnPdBmnwdciJwBECNF9vsD5lkICtqhpwZKQyHfAfDPQtp1aQkk4KkE5XP67EpCDLAQ5JtHGGrZAo8JYvu03KegK1BuLiTlP1QwFA3PjvcRszyZttBUAxM-s8cNztrcwSJrg2um3GKbktRPzPbYaeza-78GMxsOWZhEkIk_snpwGDcMEIPbj4LxHVQTVutnh7Y0LALY9TDX3Rj6a8Wd-PBbCcyLaydrPba873R6YDBoWVgvPg) wasn't helpful either, was not able to connect the replica set through the `"ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER"`

[image]

Comment: Same thing here, any news?

Comment: Maybe this can help: [Server Status hasn't become to be shown.](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/647#issuecomment-986167839) and [DOCKER - config.js ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: "true" but cannot showing the "Server Stats".](https://github.com/mongo-express/mongo-express/issues/819).

Comment: @Igor I haven't made any progress on this yet

Comment: It's probably a `already fixed bug` but still present in the last official image of `mongo-express`. You can check the discussion in the links I've put earlier. @lp_nave